# How to tell to TypeScript compiler to infer the map type?

Tags: typescript, tsc

When I write something like this:

```js
const response = await client.request('buildRoom', { users, name })

const rooms = response.result.result

const ids = rooms.map((id: string) => firestore.collection('rooms').doc(id).get())
```

I need to tell which the type of `id` is a string. But this is ok.

The problem is when I have something like this:

```js
const d = [{ result: 'aEzRuMA6AtQ6KAql8W9V' }, { result: 'N6mkKsnFJj98MHtYMxIi' }]

const result = d.map((r) => r.result)

console.log(result)
```

The code above, when I build throws the error:

> Object is of type 'unknown'.

My `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": ["src", "tests"]
}
```

Comment: *Which* line throws that error? `d` should be `{ result: string }[]` and that `.map`  should work just fine. [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJjAvDA2gbxgJwKYQK4A2UAXDAOQCGAogF4BKeAsgIIBszUAiqwNLMCOBABwB1AJwA1MjAC+AGhgYc+IqTIA5VgFsA1jwhgAYgCkAVmKGMAElACajAB4BJAJbSZAXQCwAKF+hIWGVCWGQ4ADotCgAHAApYzABKJAA+LHDgokTff3AIEAJscIIQAHME3BDEoA)

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like the [TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/vW43Km) so that others can demonstrate your issue (and only your issue) for themselves.  Right now I am unable to reproduce the problem you are having, so it's hard for me to imagine how to fix it.